# Симулятор кодового замка на java

Tags: java, netbeans

Всем привет.
Проект - симулятор кодового замка на двери. Не понимаю как к программе добавить таймер на выполнение, а так же добавить возможность сменить пароль, но только тогда когда дверь открыта. Я добавил import javax.swing.Timer, но не могу понять как сделать чтобы она заработала.

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ComboNumber extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 
int one, two, three;
String inData1, inData2, inData3;
JButton[] button;
private String secret = "5689";
private String guess = "";
public ComboNumber()
{
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Container c = getContentPane();
    button = new JButton[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) 
    {
        button[i] = new JButton("" + i);
        c.add(button[i]);
        button[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    setTitle("Comboination Lock");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
}

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      
    Object o = evt.getSource();
    if (o instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) o;
            guess += btn.getText();
        if (guess.equals(secret)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome Overloard Master");
            dispose();
        } else if (guess.length() >= 4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WRONG", "Wrong", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            guess = "";
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
    {
   ComboNumber frm = new ComboNumber();
    WindowQuitter wQuit = new WindowQuitter();
    frm.addWindowListener(wQuit);
    frm.setSize(500, 500);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class WindowQuitter extends WindowAdapter{
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
       System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы развернуть термин "таймер не выполнение", чтобы избежать разночтений. Например, можно описать требуемую функцию в формате "я как пользователь хочу чтобы когда я делаю А происходило Б [потому что B]".

Comment: Да, конечно. Я как пользователь хочу чтобы когда я введу пароль и дверь откроется через, допустим, 20 секунд происходил повторный запрос пароля.

Comment: @DaffyDuck создайте класс, унаследованный от таймера, с задержкой 1 секунду, и передайте туда свой основной класс. В таймере объявите int счетчик, а когда он достигнет 20, сделайте всё,что надо в основном классе.

Answer (score 0):

Если таймер обратного отсчета надо выводить на экран, у меня есть пример класса:
[Таймер обратного отсчета](https://github.com/PlemGitHub/GoodClassesToUse/blob/master/TimerForLevel.java)

Класс сам в себе имеет слушатель, поэтому создавать его нужно двумя командами:

```
TimerForLevel myTimer = new TimerForLevel(1000, null, 20, ваш_класс);
myTimer.addActionListener(myTimer);
```

1000 - delay;
null - в слушатель, потом добавляем.
20 - необходимое количество циклов (секунд)
ваш_класс - ссылка на класс, в котором надо что-то изменять по достижении нуля секунд.